# nz-datepicker doesn't accept manual input?

Tags: angular, ng-zorro-antd

The datepicker opens an input above it, but that doesn't seem to have any effect in selecting dates or inserting data.

I've tried even with the demos provided in the documentation, so, is that it? It does not accept user input at all or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: A datepicker that doesn't pick dates is useless, so you're likely doing something wrong. You need to provide a minimal code sample re-producing your issue.

Comment: It´s not that the datepicker doesn't pick dates, it's that I can't type dates in the input it provides me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using this datepicker then enter the value according to date format(**nz-Format**)(**MANUALLY**).

`<nz-form-label [nzSpan]="5" nzRequired>Date</nz-form-label>
      <nz-form-control [nzSpan]="5" nzHasFeedback nzErrorTip="Please choose Date">
        <nz-date-picker nzShowTime formControlName="date" nzFormat="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
          nzPlaceHolder="Select Date time"></nz-date-picker>
      </nz-form-control>
    </nz-form-item>`

Comment: It seems like it only works when there's a format explicitly specified... It works now, thanks!!

Comment: Also, noted that it only works when the date and month are the same... There's an open issue and a pull request to fix it in the ng-zorro repository